# Await Observable in Net 4.0 with Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Tags: vb.net, async-await, system.reactive, visual-studio-2015

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Comunity 2015 targeting Net 4.0 . I have installed via Nuget the followings: Rx-Main 2.2.5, Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.168. I need to await an Observable, but when i write

> `Await Observable.Return(42)`

i get a compiler error :

> "BC36930 'Await' requires that the type 'IObservable(of Integer)' have a suitable GetAwaiter method."

Note that i am able to await a `Task`, as in `Await TaskEx.FromResult(42)`, but not an Observable. I've used Object Browser to inspect Rx Library, but there is no GetAwaiter extension method, while [Github repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/v2.2.5/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable.Awaiter.cs) does contain it in System.Reactive.Linq.Observable class. Is there a way to resolve this, or should i stick to `Await Observable.Return(42).ToTask` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the implementation of GetAwaiter and INotifyCompletion is only compiled into Rx when you target .NET 4.5 and above.  Check out this [example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/2252cb4edbb25aca12005b9a912311edd2f095f3/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Subjects/AsyncSubject.cs#L271) in the source code.

This being the case, you want to use `ToTask()` to convert the observable into a task or by using one of the XXXAsync methods provided, `FirstAsync()` for example.

Comment: Yes i can await if i convert to Task, as i stated in my question. Rx [claims](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rxteam/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now/) that Observable can be directly awaited, but in my case it can't, not even Observable.FirstAsync - it fails with the same error.

Comment: @francezu13k50 I've updated my answer - it's not one that will make you happy I'm afraid...

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I would continue to target Net 4.0, be cause i need to support Windows Xp.

Comment: Yeah, it's sad, but i can't convince my client to let it die, he loves it.

Comment: However, you really should not use the MS BCL Async targeting pack now. The targeting pack should ONLY be used to target .net 4.0. **However  as of 12th Jan 2016, Microsoft has dropped support for .net 4.0.**

Comment: @francezu13k50 Your client is paying for extended support from Microsoft, right? If so, get in on those millions and ask for an appropriate padding on the support for .net 4.0.